# Reload a web page in a java application

Tags: java, browser, html, reload

I create a java application and now I have to reload a web page. I open the web page with this code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class views extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField txtHttpswwwyoutubecom;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                views frame = new views();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public views() {
    setTitle("Test");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 707, 485);
    setResizable(false);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblPutTheUrl = new JLabel("Put the url of the video");
    lblPutTheUrl.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
    lblPutTheUrl.setBounds(40, 93, 159, 24);
    contentPane.add(lblPutTheUrl);

    JLabel lblSelectTheNumber = new JLabel("Select the number");
    lblSelectTheNumber.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
    lblSelectTheNumber.setBounds(40, 200, 203, 24);
    contentPane.add(lblSelectTheNumber);

    final JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
    comboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"5", "10", "15", "20"}));
    comboBox.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
    comboBox.setBounds(322, 202, 121, 20);
    contentPane.add(comboBox);

    txtHttpswwwyoutubecom = new JTextField();
    txtHttpswwwyoutubecom.setText("https://www.google.com/");
    txtHttpswwwyoutubecom.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
    txtHttpswwwyoutubecom.setBounds(322, 93, 332, 24);
    contentPane.add(txtHttpswwwyoutubecom);
    txtHttpswwwyoutubecom.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblPressOk = new JLabel("Press Ok ");
    lblPressOk.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
    lblPressOk.setBounds(40, 298, 71, 24);
    contentPane.add(lblPressOk);

    JButton btnOk = new JButton("Ok");
    btnOk.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        private String views;
        private int intViews;

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            //trasformare il numero delle views in una stringa
            views = comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
            //trasformo stringa in int
            intViews = Integer.parseInt(views);
            System.out.println(intViews);


            //campo url
            String urls = txtHttpswwwyoutubecom.getText();


            //apertura url
            int cont=0;
            int cont1=0;
            //cont=intViews;
        //System.out.println("cont");
        //System.out.println(intViews);


            /*
             try {
                Thread.sleep(millisecondi);
                    }
                        catch (Exception e) {} 
             */
        while(intViews>cont){

            cont++;
            cont1++;
            String URL = urls;
            //String URL = "https://www.google.com/";
            try {
                java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.URI.create(URL));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                //System.exit(0);

            }
            if(cont1==5){
                cont1=0;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5500);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e1) {}

            }

            }

        }
    });
    btnOk.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
    btnOk.setBounds(322, 299, 121, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnOk);

    JLabel lblDevelopedByRiccardo = new JLabel("Developed by Riccardo Vecchiato");
    lblDevelopedByRiccardo.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
    lblDevelopedByRiccardo.setBounds(464, 421, 237, 24);
    contentPane.add(lblDevelopedByRiccardo);

    JLabel lblAlpha = new JLabel("Alpha 1.0");
    lblAlpha.setBounds(10, 428, 46, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblAlpha);


}
}
```

Every 5 seconds I open five new web page. I open that web page using this code:

```
String URL = "https://www.google.com/";
try {
    java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.URI.create(URL));
} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

There is a command that reload all the web page that I create with this code?

Comment: edit your question and add more details about your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do **not** use `Thread.sleep()` as it will freeze your Swing application.

Instead you should use a `javax.swing.Timer`.

See the Java tutorial [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) and [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information and examples.